# text and input fields hidden from HTML source

Tags: html, input

I am trying to manipulate a web page by using a web browser by automatically inserting data into certain input fields. In particular, I am trying to access the username and password fields of the following web page:
https://partnerinsight.kctrust.co.uk/Login

I can see the username and password on the web page. I can enter my data and submit it using the web page, but when I look at the source to try and find the ids for these fields. whole sections of the web page are not referenced in the source including the username and password inputs and the Login button.

My knowledge of html is limited, but I always thought it was not possible to do this.

Am I wrong? Is there a way of doing what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the html is added to the source with JS,
Try pressing the inputs with right-mouse-button and 'inspect element' (in chrome)
then you will see those fields:

```
<div class="form-line">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder=" Username" name="Username" data-bind="value:Username">
        </div>
```

Hope it legit :)

Comment: Thanks. I can see the the input source with inspect element. My problem is that I'm using the mshtml type library. When I use IHTMLDocument to get all the tags it is not find these hidden tags so I can't programatically manipulate them using IHTMLInputElement to set the value. Any idea how I can get at these tags using mshtml or is it just not possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those tools.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome there's a handy little button called "find in page" It can access html that is hidden, or generated with JavaScript.
[image]